# Given the url of a page how can I access the html, and use regex to extract the html between a certain div?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Given a URL of a webpage, I need to get the HTML between an opening `<div>` and a closing `</div>` of a particular class.

I think if I can return the whole html code of the page as a string I could use RegEx to extract between the HTML between the certain `<div>` class and return it as a string.

How could we achieve this using Objective-C and RegExes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the parsing part, I have 3 words for you:

> **Don't try it**

Read [Parsing HTML the Cthulhu Wya](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) (by Jeff himself) and see [this ever-famous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). For libraries, use [HTML::Sanitizer](http://search.cpan.org/~nesting/HTML-Sanitizer-0.04/Sanitizer.pm)

On the other hand, most programs will neither need to, nor should, anticipate the entire universe of HTML when parsing. In fact, designing a program to do so may well be a completely wrong-headed approach, if it changes a program from a few-line script to a bullet-proof commercial-grade program which takes orders of magnitude more time to properly code and support. Resource expenditure should always (oops, make that very frequently, I about overgeneralized, too) be considered when creating a programmatic solution.
In addition, hard boundaries need not always be an HTML-oriented limitation. They can be as simple as "work with these sets of web pages", "work with this data from these web pages", "work for 98% users 98% of the time", or even "OMG, we have to make this work in the next hour, do the best you can".

So if you're parsing something like [icanhazip](http://icanhazip.com), you can opt for it. Maybe if it's small, it might work. Or if you're using static content. That's for you to choose. Good luck!

Comment: How would you strip a div out from a html page and keep the html?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if string match a regex with `NSPredicate`

This code will check if `_test` is an email address

```
-(BOOL)CheckInput:(NSString *)_text  
{  
    NSString *Regex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";  
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicatepredicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];   
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:_text];  
}
```